# Read binary string, use as binary string python

Tags: python-3.x, input, binary

I have a binary string "list" as input and want it to be saved as matrix of binaries which I then can use for logical operations (params coming as sys.argv[x]).

Example:

```
python3 k n matrix
python3 2 2 1101S101S111S1000
```

Should become a matrix (2D Array, numpy array, whatever) where I can make XOR, AND etc operations.
So something like that:

```
[[1101, 101], [111, 1000]]
```

There are heaps of manuals about binaries in the Internet, but none which really fits what I am trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following. Given your string, it seems that `S` is the delimiter between your binary strings. So split on them and simply reshape using numpy

```
import numpy as np
n = 2
k = 2
s = '1101S101S111S1000'
tokens = s.split('S')
np.array(tokens).reshape(n,k)
```

which yields

```
array([['1101', '101'],
       ['111', '1000']], dtype='<U4')
```